# How to convert Python key based sort code to GO key based sort code

Tags: opencv, go

I am new to GO. I am converting a code from python to go. And i want to convert this line to `GO`. I looked over google but couldn't found any supporting solution.
I am having hard time with this.

```
# this will slice top five contour based on area
cnt = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]
```

Where i am taking contours `[][]image.Point` type as per go.

Any ideas how can i deal with it?

Comment: For sorting slices have you looked at https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to sort your slice with the `sort` package, and then you can pick the top five in the same manner (using `[:5]`).

You'll likely have to write some custom methods to guide the sort in the exact way you want it. There are several examples in the [documentation of the sort package](https://pkg.go.dev/sort) - e.g. see `SortKeys`.

[Another example from gobyexample](https://gobyexample.com/sorting-by-functions) shows how:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type byLength []string

func (s byLength) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}
func (s byLength) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
func (s byLength) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return len(s[i]) < len(s[j])
}

func main() {
    fruits := []string{"peach", "banana", "kiwi"}
    sort.Sort(byLength(fruits))
    fmt.Println(fruits)
}
```